# Injecting several Spring Beans of the same class using application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a security test driven by Spring.  I want to create a set of test users (currentUser, anotherUser, adminUser, etc).  The credentials for the users will be stored in an application.properties like so:

```
test.currentUser.username=user1
test.currentUser.password=secret
test.adminUser.username=admin
test.adminUser.password=admin_password
...
```

There is a class that can construct an object for a user.  It looks something like this:

```
@Component
public class UserObject{
  public UserObject(
    @Value("${test.currentUser.username}") String username,
    @Value("${test.currentUser.password}") String password){
    //Use username and password to do some authentication stuff
  }
}
```

The client test class looks something like this:

```
public class TestClass{
  @Autowired
  public TestClass(UserObject userObject){
  }
}
```

How can the classes above be altered such that several UserObjects are somehow injected by Spring (and get config values from the application.properties file)?

Comment: are you using spring boot ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ConfigurationProperties
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
public class Test {
  Map<String, String> credentials;
}


@Configuration
public class TestCreate {

  @Bean(name = "userList")
  public List<UserObject> creteUser(Test test) {
    List<UserObject> users = new ArrayList<>();
    test.getCredentials().entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
      UserObject user = new UserObject( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
      users.add(user);
    });
    return users;
  }
}
```

application.properties

```
credentials.user1=secret //user1 is key, secret is value
credentials.user2=someothersecret
```

Now if you do

```
@Autowired
List<UserObject> userList;
```

in any of the spring component, you get what you desired. 
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
test:
   users:
       - user1,secret1
       - user2,secret2
```

Would be transformed into these properties:

```
test.users[0]={user1, secret1}
test.users[1]={user2, secret2}


@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="test")
public class Config {

    private List<String[]> users= new ArrayList<String[]>();

    public List<String[]> getUsers() {
        return this.servers;
    }
}
```

[24.6.1 Loading YAML](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

I didn't try it but it should work.